# Name of song Boruto episode 73

Tags: music, boruto

does anyone know that name of the song that starts at 17:50 in the last episode of boruto (73) I can't find it anywhere. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Boruto Unreleased OST - Virtue :DDD